# Mass Assignment with tinker in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

While following tutorial, i've stumbled upon this issue. I've fixed problem, but tinker is still giving me an error.

```
>>> $book = App\books::create(['title' => 'New Book', 'description' => 'New Description']);
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException with message 'title'
>>> $book = App\books::create(['title' => 'New Book', 'description' => 'New Description']); trace
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException with message 'title'
```

I've made an array for title & description. It's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to your books model add this:

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'description'];
```

Comment: I figured the problem. I had to restart the tinker and it worked.